# Instantiation relationship between multiple classes

Tags: c#

So i have 3 classes and i'm trying to make them work with each other. One is a student class which each student has a name and form, the next is a class which is meant to hold the school roster in a list. The last is a class which holds the operations to be done on the list(adding students, getting the students in a particular form and getting all students in the school list). When i instanstiate the student class and try to add it using the opertion class it gives an error telling me that the list does not exist in the current context.

```
class Exercises
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    school Showers = new school();
    student Lenny = new student("Lenny",4);
    Operation.AddStudent(Lenny);
  }
}

public class student
{
  private string Name;
  private int Form;


  public student(string n, int f)
  {
    Form = f;
    Name = n;
  }

  public string GetName()
  {
      return this.Name;
  }

}

public class Operation
{
  public static void AddStudent(student st)
  {
    schoolRoster.Add(st);
  }

  public static void PrintForm(int num)
  {
    foreach (Student stu in schoolRoster)
    {
        if ((st.Form == num ))
        {
             Console.WriteLine(st.Name);
        }
    }
  }

  public static void PrintAll()
  {
    foreach (student stu in schoolRoster)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(st.Name+" in form "+st.Form);   
    }
  }

}

public class school
{
  List<student> schoolRoster = new List<student>();
}
```

Comment: And that's correct. There is no `var ops = new Operation();`

Comment: The `Operation` class has multiple references to a field called `schoolRoster`, but that class has no such field.  Perhaps instead of an `Operation` class you meant to put all of those operations on the `school` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void AddStudent(student st)
  {
    schoolRoster.Add(st);
  }
```

An object can only access local variables or fields and properties of the class itself. `schoolRoster` is defined in the `School` class, so cannot be accessed in the `Operation`-class. Not unless it has a `School` object to access it thru.

Further more the method is marked as `static`. This means it can be called without first creating an object. But also means it cannot access any fields or properties of the class, unless they are also marked as `static`. But while static methods are fine, you need to be very careful with making fields or data static, since this can easily result in unmaintanable code.

But a core point in object orientation is that methods should be associated with the data they operate on. If all your methods operate on `schoolRoster`, they should probably be part of the `school` class, and `schoolRoster` should be made private, so that all access to the roster is made thru the methods of the class.

```
public class School
{
    private List<student> schoolRoster = new ();
    public void AddStudent(student st) => schoolRoster.Add(st);
}
...
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    School showers = new ();
    student lenny = new ("Lenny",4);
    showers.AddStudent(lenny);
}
```